# No match for operand< passing objects

Tags: c++, overloading, operands

I have two classes, one, Obj when i calculate the Median of the set, and an other that should do some operator overload

I also have put the operator< in the second class, (where i have a vector of the 2st class object, and trying to passing object to main to using the operand. But it continues to gives me no match for operand<

My 1st class:

```
template<typename T>
class Obj {
private:
    typedef vector <T> myins;
    myins insieme;

public:
    Obj() {}

    void Add(const T& o) {
        insieme.push_back(o);
    }

    void Remove() {
        insieme.pop_back();
    }

    int Mediana() {

        sort(insieme.begin(), insieme.end());

        typename myins::const_iterator iter;
        typename myins::const_iterator iter1;

        double mediana = 0, result = 0;
        int risultato = 0;

        if (insieme.size() % 2 != 0) {
            mediana = (insieme.size() + 1) ;
            mediana /= 2;
            result = round(mediana);
            iter = insieme.begin()+result-1;
            risultato = *iter;
        }
        else {
            mediana = round(insieme.size()/2) ;
            iter = insieme.begin()+mediana-1;
            double mediana1 = mediana +1;
            iter1 = insieme.begin()+mediana1-1;
            risultato = round (*iter+*iter1);
            risultato /= 2;
        }

        return (risultato);
    }
};
```

The second class:

```
template<typename T>
class ListaObj {

private:
    vector<T> myobjs;

public:
    ListaObj() {}

    void AddObj(T& ob) {
        myobjs.push_back(ob);
    }

    inline T& GetObj( int i ) {
        return myobjs[i];
    }

    friend bool operator<(const T& o1, const T& o2) {
        if ( o1.Mediana() < o2.Mediana() ) return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
 };
```

And my main:

```
int main() {

     Obj<int> o1;
     Obj<int> o2;
     ListaObj<Obj<int>> list;

     o1.Add(2);
     o1.Add(3);
     o1.Add(3);
     o1.Add(5);
     o1.Add(7);
     o1.Add(10);

     o2.Add(1);
     o2.Add(2);
     o2.Add(3);

     list.AddObj(o1);
     list.AddObj(o2);

     auto obj1 = list.GetObj(0);
     auto obj2 = list.GetObj(1);



     cout << "Mediana o1: "<<o1.Mediana() << endl;
     cout << "Mediana o2: "<<o2.Mediana() << endl;

    bool tr = obj1 < obj2;

    if (tr) {
        cout << "Mediana di o1 minore di o2";
    }
    else
        cout << "o2 minore di o1";


    return 0;
}
```

Until of the cout Mediana 01 and Mediana 02 in the main it works perfectly and gives the right result, but at the overload, it gives :

> |135|error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'Obj' and 'Obj')|

I'm searching and trying from 2 hours, but nothing solves my problem, what i'm doing wrong?
Thank you

I need to do the operator overload< (and others) to return if the Median of the first obj, is < then the second, using two class and a vector of Objs

Comment: Why are you trying to overload `operator<` on `ListaObj` instead of `Obj`? The `operator<` you defined kinda looks like it's intended to work for `Obj` given the templating, but it's nonsensical for `ListaObj` to define the ordering of some unrelated object...

Comment: You should define `bool operator<(const Obj&) const;` as a member of  `Obj`. `operator<` in `ListaObj` in your code is ill-formed and not needed.

Comment: Also `int Mediana()` should be `const` since you call it from const .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the compiler error carefully.
The "less than" operator is overloaded in class `ListaObj`, while you try to compare `obj1` and `obj2`, which are two objects of type `Obj`.